# How to extract data from a txt file and rename it to smaller files

Tags: matlab, text-files

Does anyone know how I can extract data from a txt file. My text file has 3 columns and I'm basically trying to extract the first 30 rows and save it as a different txt file. Then the next 30 and so on until I'm left with multiple smaller text files, each with 30 rows of data in them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`fgets`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgets.html) to retrieve each line of the input, and [`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) to write the output to the new files. It really doesn't care how many columns of data you have. It will all be preserved.

```
lines_per_file = 30;

% Load the source file
fin = fopen('input.txt', 'r');

% Retrieve the first line
line = fgets(fin);

% Keep track of how many lines are in the current file
nLines = 0;
nFiles = 1;

% Loop until we have read all lines
while line ~= -1

    % Check to see if we need to start a new file
    if mod(nLines, lines_per_file) == 0
        % Close the old file if it's open and exists
        if exist('fout', 'var'); fclose(fout); end

        % Open the output file of the format output.XX.txt
        fout = fopen(sprintf('output_%d.txt', nFiles), 'w');
        nFiles = nFiles + 1;
    end

    % Write the line to the output
    fprintf(fout, line);

    % Retrieve the next line
    line = fgets(fin);
    nLines = nLines + 1;
end

% Clean up file identifiers.
fclose(fout);
fclose(fin);
```

This will take the input file ('input.txt') and create N output files of the format:

```
output_1.txt
output_2.txt
...
output_N.txt
```

Comment: @Crowley Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the file closing in the answer. I wanted to keep the naming convention for the output file in one place so that's why I have don't have fout defined at first. I could set it to an empty array, but then I'd have to check if it's empty rather than checking if the variable exists as calling fclose on an empty array leads to an error.

Comment: In your case You define the naming convention in one place only, I'd have to keep in mind two lines where name convention is defined.

Comment: @Crowley Ok that's what I figured. Too bad `fclose([])` errors out.